# Where can I find the original bhaagwat text of gopi vastra haran by Krishna incident?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana

I am looking for the original text with hindi or english translation of Krishna stealing gopis clothes while they were bathing in a river naked.

I have heard that it is written in the original text that Krishna did this act out of sexual desire to see gopis naked.

So the word that I am told used in the bhagwat for that act is "kaamaatur" (कामातुर) meaning out of lust.

I have nothing against this word or feeling I just want to confirm if this word is really used in the original text for that particular incident.

Comment: Kṛṣṇa had no interest (sexual) in seeing the gopīs naked, he was a child (of about 6 yrs) at that time, who hadn't even entered teenage and many gopīs were children too, like him. Also, he is a pūrṇāvatāra, not a slave of vāsanās like ordinary manuṣyas who would waver with sexual attraction. Who can attract Īśvara himself? In fact, he criticized the gopīs that they were bathing nude in Yamunā (nagnaḥ snānam is niṣiddha, as per śāstras). As for the narration of that incident in Bhāgavata, you may check (10.22) i.e. 22nd adhyāya in 10th skandha. You may check the translation by Gītā press. –

Comment: Here's a [Hindī translation](https://archive.org/details/srimad-bhagavat-mahapuran-2-volume-set-sanskrit-hindi/Srimad%20Bhagavat%20Mahapuran%20Volume%202%20Sanskrit%20Hindi/). And english translation (by [Tagare](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128888.html) ; by [Gita Press](https://archive.org/details/bhagavatapuranagitapress_201907/mode/2up?view=theater)) 
His act of taking away the clothes of gopīs might seem an act of mischief on the surface, but it wasn't so at all.

Comment: Also, it clearly states I believe the Gopis secretly felt a sense of joy internally, but externally were ashamed, Narayana is Bhagavan, so he knew their thoughts, but he also knew what they were doing was wrong, so I see no ill omen also yes age makes things very different.